# Drawing on Canvas - onload not executed

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

i try to darw multiple Images into a canvas.

I use js to Archive this

```
//in draw method:
 Images[counter] = new Image();
    Images[counter].src = "/anImage.png";
    for (var i = counter; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        attach(ctx, Images[i], xCordinates[i], yCordinates[i]);
    }

function attach (cont, img, x, y) {
    try
    {

        img.onload = function () {

            cont.drawImage(this, x, y);
        }
    }
    catch(ex)
    {
        alert(ex);
    }
}
```

The Trouble i have is, taht the images arent shwon properly. in fact, only the last Image is displayed. i check my code an im absolutly sure that the coordinates i submit to the "attach"- method are correct. Due Debugging i find out, taht the onload is only executed for the last Image in the Loop, what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of an image loader that will load all images and then call the start() function.

All code in start() can rely on the fact that all images are fully loaded:

```
// image loader

// put the paths to your images in imageURLs[]
var imageURLs=[];  
// push your image urls!
imageURLs.push("");

// the loaded images will be placed in images[]
var imgs=[];

var imagesOK=0;
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array now holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

    // example
    for(var i=0;i<imgs.length;i++){
        cont.drawImage(imgs[i],i*30,i*30);
    }

}
```